# Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining

Tags: anchor, devnet, deploy, blockhash

trying to deploy a program to the devnet I keep encountering this issue when my program just tries and retry to deploy with no success, any idea why this may be?:

[image]

````
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/juan/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.25/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/scripts/strip.sh /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/anchor_nft_staking.so /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/deploy/anchor_nft_staking.so
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/juan/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.25/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf --dyn-symbols /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/deploy/anchor_nft_staking.so

To deploy this program:
  $ solana program deploy /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/deploy/anchor_nft_staking.so
The program address will default to this keypair (override with --program-id):
  /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/deploy/anchor_nft_staking-keypair.json
Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /Users/juan/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "lootbox-program"...
Program path: /Users/juan/anchor-nft-staking-program/target/deploy/lootbox_program.so...
Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
=======================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=======================================================================
uncle okay cheap deny dentist argue reunion depth anxiety own soup true
=======================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=======================================================================
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.```
````

Comment: It would be helpful to have a bit more information on the nature of the failure -- does it stall out? Does it return any error messages? If so, what are they? And please paste plain-text output formatted in code blocks rather than screenshots.

Comment: i edited my question adding the complete terminal output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed by installing Solana SDK v1.13.3 from [Github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/). I confirmed that v1.10.40 has the problem above. `solana-install update` does NOT update to a functioning version, you must download the latest SDK from the web.

The buffer account gets initialized properly.
However The problem was when it sends the 177 transactions to write data to the buffer account, this uploading happens in a loop until the blockhash expires 5 times. I speculate this may be cause by the migration from UDP to QUIC?

```
solana program write-buffer --buffer 7sKxfuKsax7RVhnBbxmKnPJxYT5zq4T4sNxy8ghTK1AE target/deploy/small_program.so -u d 
⠈   0.0% | Waiting for next block, 177 pending...   [block height 162127887; re-sign in 121 blocks]
⠚   0.0% | Sending 92/177 transactions
⠤   0.0% | Waiting for next block, 177 pending...   [block height 162127892; re-sign in 116 blocks]
⠚   0.0% | Sending 41/177 transactions
Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining
⠲   0.0% | Waiting for next block, 177 pending...   [block height 162128014; re-sign in 300 blocks]
^C
```

Comment: I updated to v1.13.3 and ran the commands `anchor deploy` or `solana program deploy -u devnet target/deploy/**/<PROGRAM.so>` and I keep getting the blockhash expired...any pointers?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue for me too, just followed these installation steps: https://docs.solana.com/es/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#macos--linux
as @Tristyn said `solana-install update` didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by reinstalling solana from [sources](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana) so it matches deployed cluster solana version.

```
doge> solana cluster-version
1.13.3


doge> solana --version
solana-cli 1.13.3 (src:devbuild; feat:4011803773)
```