# Blockhash expeired error when deploy program to devnet

Tags: devnet, deploy

When I deploy the solana program to devnet, I am getting below error.

[image]

And it says to me `Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded`
I am using solana-cli(1.14.7).
How can I solve that?

Comment: I think this might be the same issue as https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/blockhash-expired-5-retries-remaining, except that was on an older version than you're on.

Based on one of the answers there, what do you get if you run `solana cluster-version`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by updating the CLI.

> ```
> solana-install update
> ```

or.

> ```
> sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.13.2/install)"
> ```